# Rmarkdown with pdf output and plain LaTeX code block

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

How to do a plain code block with `rmarkdown` when this code block contains some `tex` code and one wants the pdf output ?

For example, this does not work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

Hello !

```
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
```
````

This generated this error: *! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{verbatim}.*

Of course, I can do:

````
```{r, eval=FALSE}
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
```
````

But the problem when doing that, is that the code block in the output can be highlighted by the R highlighting colors (not for the example above, but this could occur in some cases).

Comment: Not sure if there currently is a way to do this. Some implementations of markdown (e.g. Github's) allow you do specify a specific syntax to use for the code block so you could do something like "```tex", but RMarkdown doesn't seem to recognize this.

If you only have a few instances where you want to do this, your best bet might be to use an online HTML syntax highlighter to convert the latex into HTML and copy and paste that into the Rmd file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pandoc's verbatim fenced code block](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#verbatim-code-blocks) syntax:

```
~~~latex
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
~~~
```

Or also:

````
```latex
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
```
````

Comment: Oh ! In fact this also works with three backticks too ! So far I tried `tex` instead of `latex` which doesn't work.

Comment: Consequently, scoa, I took the liberty to edit your answer in order to add the solution with the backticks.